# Interceptor in Angular, only for some calls?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following factory in my Angular App. It is used to add bearer token information, to the header of all my outgoing request with $resource. It works as expected.

But i have implemented some external calls, which should not be added with the bearer token. How do i implement a check, so i can control what calls are getting intercepted and which are not?

My code:

```
.factory('authInterceptor', [
      "$q", "$window", "$location", "currentUser", function ($q, $window, $location, currentUser) {
          return {
              request: function(config) {
                  config.headers = config.headers || {};
                  config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token;
                  return config;
              },
              response: function(response) {
                  return response || $q.when(response);
              },
              responseError: function(rejection) {
                  // error handler
              }
          };
      }
    ])
```

Add the authInterceptor:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
}])
```

Factory for a resource:

```
myApp.factory('Random', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('domain.com', { }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

Call the resource:

```
Random.query({ });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, for example, you can do something in the request object,

```
    .factory('authInterceptor', [
          "$q", "$window", "$location", "currentUser", function ($q, $window, $location, currentUser) {
              return {
                  request: function(config) {
if(config.url !== 'external url') {
                      config.headers = config.headers || {};
                      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + currentUser.getProfile().token;
}
                      return config;
                  },
                  response: function(response) {
                      return response || $q.when(response);
                  },
                  responseError: function(rejection) {
                      // error handler
                  }
              };
          }
        ])
```

with that conditional, you will skip unwanted url mods.
check out the doc as well,
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage
you can even create a key for all calls, that switches the interception on / off.